# CreateFile with security descriptor adds user but no rights

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I need to create a new folder and I need to make it accessible to everyone. I have found out that it can be done with using security descriptors and so I have found some code examples in C++ and tried to create directory. It does create the folder, but there is an issue, the user is added to security tab, but it has no checks at either deny or allow for all of the options except allow for special permissions. I thought I had done something wrong (even though I literally copied the code from MSDN and some other places when that failed - but all with the same result). So I tried the same thing in C#, with exactly the same result.

The code I used is (C#):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
            securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow));

            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\sharpTest", securityRules);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried several combinations of user accounts, rights and allow/deny, but all come up the same, with user being addded, but no checks. Is there some other thing that needs to be added? This isn't a 5 minute search I did, I tried to get this working for about 2 days in total (over a few weeks), trying a whole lot of combinations (but that was in C++). C# seems to be a nobrainer, but produces the same thing.

Regards

Comment: Check the advanced security settings dialog. Also, have a look at the full [`FileSystemAccessRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw) constructor. Hopefully this clarifies that "full control" of a directory in the simple security dialog entails full control over the directory itself as well as its subdirectories and files (i.e. `ContainerInherit | ObjectInherit`), with the option to limit inheritance propagation to just the "objects and/or containers within this container" (i.e. `NoPropagateInherit`).

Comment: Actually, I specifically want to set it to have all rights at creation as I might not have them afterwards. Even so, I'm afraid I might not be able to create it without sufficient privileges.